# Get php file from instance of object

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to get the file location of an object? The object is an instance of a class but i'd like to know where this class is located on the file system based on an instance of this class.

Is this possible somehow in PHP?

Comment: Do you use autoloader in order to instantiate a class, without expliclitly require it, because in PHP to make instance of class, you need to include the file, but to include it manually you need to know the path

Comment: `$reflection = new ReflectionClass($your_object);echo $reflection->getFileName();` - however - why? You should use an IDE that helps you find class definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection is the way to go, especially [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

Comment: ReflectionClass::getFileName() should do :) +1